# Cannot remove play music icon from applications viewer in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, uninstall, music

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and I use google chrome browser. Recently I installed play music mini player and after that I saw there were two play music icons in my applications viewer. I uninstalled the play music plugin from chrome however there is still another play music icon:
[image: screenshot]
and on clicking it, another window of chrome opens.I cannot remove this play music icon. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory and you should find a launcher associated to the Play Music webapp. Simply move/delete the file.

Note that the launcher may not look like a Play Music icon, but just may appear as text file with the `.desktop` suffix. You'll have to open such files with a text editor and view their content to recognise the correct one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved my problem. The launcher was in the form of a text file with .desktop suffix however on opening it, there will be a section called Name. I checked whichever file's name was Google Play Music and simply removed it. [Please note: The file names of the launchers might be gibberish and you have to open each file individually to see which is the correct file.] Thank you. :)